# Firebase subaccounts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building a POS/Store admin app, when a user gets into my app, the Owner of the store will then be asked to login only once for setup purpose (e.g. a new machine), the app will then display a list of staffsName that has already been added by this owner, and then everytime a staff wants to start a new transaction, he/she will only need to click on his/her name, then enter his/her 4-digit pincode to 'login' and process the transaction.

How do i go about achieving this?
I was thinking of using firebase auth for the 'login' of the staff, but then when i log in using the staff credential, I will lose access to the uid of the owner, which is needed to access the owner's store data such as his/her products.

i'm also thinking of using firestore to store the 4digit pincode, but then i'm also concerned about security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can approach this, one where you utilize the email login by simply appending a fake domain to the username to create a valid email domain. This user account could be the designated 'user' in question, or utilize credentials inside custom claims or hidden in a database that allows the client or server (depending on your preference) to then log in as the user.

Moreover if you want the manager to login once you can add [Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) to specify whether a signed in user should be indefinitely persisted until explicit sing out, page reload etc.

Another approach requires the user also to have a valid auth that is not an email password and you link your pin auth to that main account with Firebase Auth Linking per the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking.

This does however require that the user be registered from an auth provider such as Google, Twitter, Apple, etc. then the user will have to activate this link by logging in for authentication purposes. This can in theory be automatically generated and processed without the user knowing.

It is a long way around it since this is essentially a custom solution but it does create the flow you are looking for without having to use a custom auth provider.

Comment: if my answer helped, would you mind accepting it? or giving some feedback? thank you.

Comment: @YosuaMartiansia  Updated the answer with more details about Authentication State Persistence.